# helm help mode can not search or select

Tags: helm

While in Helm Help mode -- the help buffer that pops up when you hit `C-c ?` in a helm buffer -- I am unable to do anything but scroll up and down. I can not select text (neither with mouse nor with keys), or `C-s` search or anything!

Is this a feature or a bug? Can I change this behavior, and have, say, a regular read-only buffer, where at the minimum text selection works?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it's by design, but I'm also interested in ways to "escape" to the buffers helm creates...

Comment: You should submit a feature request to Helm maintainer through Github.

Comment: See this answer http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28675/bindings-in-helm-help?noredirect=1&lq=1 for a way to add bindings to helm help buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. Here is the feature request:

https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/887